# How does :normal! /something<cr> relate to incsearch and the / operator?

Tags: vim

A few micro-questions regarding *normal!, incsearch and the / operator (search)*. I'm not solving any particular problem here, just trying to understand the relations between the mentioned, so I can put up some sort of analogy in my head.

If I have, *set incsearch* on, while in normal mode upon pressing */something* Vim will jump to the first instance of *something* even before/without me pressing enter.

Okey, so *normal! /something* should do the same thing. **Why doesn't it?**

Similarly, *normal!*  doesn't recognize special characters. So if I have a text file with this text in it,

```
something<cr>
```

(that's not a special character in there, but literally typed in text)

```
`normal! /something<cr>`
```

should put me up to that text. **Why doesn't it?**

***I like it, but sometimes Vim's inconsistencies are, to put it mildly, most interesting :)***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `:help :normal` the relevant text is:

```
{commands} should be a complete command.  If
{commands} does not finish a command, the last one
will be aborted as if <Esc> or <C-C> was typed.
```

The command string you give to `normal` has to be a complete command, or it aborts. However, `normal! /something` isn't complete; if you were typing it, Vim would be waiting for you to finish. You could press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to abort. Or you could complete it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. So the command isn't complete and it aborts, instead of jumping. To get it to complete, give it the Enter it wants (at the command line):

```
:normal! /something^M
```

You can get the `^M` by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (If on Windows and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> pastes, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>.) Then you'll need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to finish the whole command. If you were using `execute` you could do it with:

```
:execute "normal! /something\<cr>"
```

Be sure to use double-quotes so the `\<cr>` will be interpreted correctly.

I believe your second question is the same thing. The literally typed `<cr>` doesn't affect this situation, you just need to provide the carriage return that will complete the search command, or `normal` aborts it.

Since you've tagged this question with [vimscript](/questions/tagged/vimscript), I'm guessing that at least part of your interest is in using this in a script. Getting the literal carriage return into a script and having it work right is kind of a pain. In those cases, I would use `execute` as shown above, so you can use the double-quote interpretted string method of getting the carriage return.

As for `incsearch`, it won't have an effect because you can't be partially searching with `normal`, as we've seen. You can only submit the entire search. It will, however, update the most-recent-search register `"/`, so highlighting will still update correctly.

Comment: +1 ... now if I could only remember what I was doing at the time, and what I needed that for ;)